# mod_rewrite RewriteRule backreference use in pattern

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, backreference

Is it possible to use a backreference in the middle of the RewriteRule *pattern*?

I envision this as such:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.)([a-z]*)$1([a-z]*)  $2-$3
                          ^
     (note, this fellow, here, refers to that first "(.)")
```

If the received url is `XboopXdoop`, the result would of course be `boop-doop`.

I am attempting to use this to specify a delimiter at the beginning of the incoming url that can be used to parse the rest of the string, without forcing the use of a specific character as that delimiter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$1` works on the right side (rewrite), but not in the regex.  You need to use `\1`.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.)([a-z]+)\1([a-z]+) $2-$3
```

I ran into a bizarre edge case with the `*` where it split based on the second character of the string, and not the second.  `XtestingXtest` resulted in `es-ing` ... so yeah, not sure what was happening there.  If I use a `+` it works fine.

Also, since `*` and `+` are greedy, if you have multiple delimiter characters, it will split on the last occurrence of the character:

```
XbaseXtest  -> base-test 
XbaseXteXst -> baseXte-st
XbaseXtestX -> baseXtest-
```

Comment: Awesome!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much!  There was a site getting persnickety about including query strings in external script sources, so supplying, say, `.../_X_pageXfield=val`, where `^_(.)(.*)\1(.*)$` was the pattern and `$2?$3` its result, managed to get around the issue.